# how to use react select in nextjs, it gives me an error onChange

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using reactjs and nextjs I included react select npm, now in below code I'm getting error at onChange={handleWarnaChange} please help me to solve this issue I am new to nextjs and reactjs

```
  const [warna, setWarna] = useState([]);
  const [ukuran, setUkuran] = useState([]);
  const optionsWarna = [
    { value: "biru", label: "Biru" },
    { value: "kuning", label: "Kuning" },
    { value: "hijau", label: "Hijau" },
    { value: "cokelat", label: "Cokelat" },
    { value: "merah", label: "Merah" }
  ];

  const optionsUkuran = [
    { value: "S", label: "S" },
    { value: "M", label: "M" },
    { value: "L", label: "L" },
    { value: "XL", label: "XL" },
    { value: "XXL", label: "XXL" }
  ];
  const handleWarnaChange = async (selected: React.SetStateAction<never[]>, selectaction: { action: any; }) => {
    const { action } = selectaction;
    // console.log(`action ${action}`);
    if (action === "clear") {
    } else if (action === "select-option") {
    } else if (action === "remove-value") {
      console.log("remove");
    }
    setWarna(selected);
  };
  const handleUkuranChange = async (selected: React.SetStateAction<never[]>, selectaction: {action: any;}) => {
    // const { action } = selectaction;
    setUkuran(selected);
  };


//below code is in return
   <Select
        id="selectWarna"
        instanceId="selectWarna"
        isMulti
        name="colors"
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        options={optionsWarna}
        onChange={handleWarnaChange}
        placeholder="Pilih Warna"
      />
```